# Catching a right angle.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a right-angle trapezoid where $AB||CD$ and $AD$ $\bot$ $AB$, and let $M$ be the midpoint of $AD$. Let $BC=AB+CD$ and let $S$ be a point on $BC$,such that $CS=CD$. Prove first that angle $ASD$ is a right angle then use this to show that angle $MDS=MSD$.
[image]

**Efforts made:** I've been able to prove that angle $MDS=MSD$ and using that i've been able to prove $ASD$ is a right angle,but the problem asks me to do otherwise and i cant see how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated.Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part:

As $CD=CS$ we  get that angles $\sphericalangle CDS=\sphericalangle CSD$. Also as $BC=AB+CD$ we have that $AB=BS$ and so angles $\sphericalangle BAS=\sphericalangle BSA$.

Note that angles $\sphericalangle BAD$ and $\sphericalangle ADC$ are right angles.

Moreover $\sphericalangle BSA+\sphericalangle ASD+\sphericalangle CSD = \pi$ (*), $\sphericalangle DAS = {\pi}/{2} - \sphericalangle BAS$, and $\sphericalangle ADS={\pi}/{2} - \sphericalangle CDS$.

Also $\sphericalangle DAS + \sphericalangle ADS + \sphericalangle ASD = \pi$.

From above, you can rewrite $\sphericalangle ASD = \sphericalangle BAS + \sphericalangle CDS = \sphericalangle BSA+ \sphericalangle CSD$. (**)

Finally combine (*) and (**) to get $\sphericalangle ASD = \pi / 2$.

For the second part:

Use a converse of Thales' theorem.